# Cvxpy Error "Cannot multiply two non-constants"

Tags: python

Пытаюсь решить задачу оптимизации с помощью `cvxpy`.

```
import numpy as np
import cvxpy as cvx

m = 100
n = 100

A = np.random.randn(m, n)

b = cvx.Variable(m)
c = cvx.Variable(n)

x0 = np.ones(n)

x = cvx.Variable(n)

obj = cvx.Minimize(c * x)

constraints = [b == A * x0, A * x - b, c == -cvx.sum_entries(A)]

prob = cvx.Problem(obj, constraints)

print "Optimal value", prob.solve()
print "Optimal var"
print x.value
```

Появляется следующая ошибка: `line 16, in <module> obj = cvx.Minimize(c * x)`

```
cvxpy.error.DCPError: Cannot multiply two non-constants.
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: Приведите трассировку полностью или напишите на какой строчке произошла ошибка.

Comment: памятка: [Я случайно создал две учетных записи, как их объединить?](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)

Answer (score 0):

Я не знаток в области данной задачи, но это просто сторонний взгляд.
Попробуйте проверить эту идею: https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-solve-non-linear-kernel-support-vector-machine-SVM-with-CVX
Но на сколько я могу понять незнакомую библиотеку с первого взгляда, **x** и **c** задаются как параметры для оптимизации, а задача оптимизации - минимизация их произведения - в данном случае оптимизация по обоим параметрам равнозначна и с точки зрения математики (на мое неполноценное понимание задачи) решения два: когда один параметр равен бесконечности, а другой минус бесконечности, что может затруднять процесс оптимизации.